# Chunked upload (resumable upload) for OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive

I'd like to upload a large file (say 500MB) to OneDrive, but I cannot find any API to do chunked upload. There is one similar question [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c4aaa90c-dc75-441f-9b30-f5c45e402ac4/limitation-on-api-requestfile-size-limitationresume-upload?forum=onedriveapi) without explicit answer. It looks like there is no support to chunked upload currently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, we currently do not support this.

Comment: I've recorded this request in our backlog for the API. It's definitely something we've heard before and are investigating options for how we can provide that functionality.

Answer (score 2):

OneDrive  already  support  chunking   upload

https://gist.github.com/rgregg/37ba8929768a62131e85

Comment: Because it requires the `Content-Length` being set it is not feasible for some use cases where the file size is not known in advance. The API lacks support for chunked encodings.