# Chunk download with OneDrive Rest API

Tags: c++, rest, onedrive, casablanca

this is the first time I write on StackOverflow. My question is the following.

I am trying to write a OneDrive C++ API based on the cpprest sdk CasaBlanca project:

https://casablanca.codeplex.com/

In particular, I am currently implementing read operations on OneDrive files.

Actually, I have been able to download  a whole file with the following code:

```
http_client api(U("https://apis.live.net/v5.0/"), m_http_config);

api.request(methods::GET, file_id +L"/content" ).then([=](http_response response){
    return response.body();
}).then([=]( istream is){
    streambuf<uint8_t> rwbuf = file_buffer<uint8_t>::open(L"test.txt").get();
    is.read_to_end(rwbuf).get();
    rwbuf.close();
}).wait()
```

This code is basically downloading the whole file on the computer (file_id is the id of the file I am trying to download). Of course, I can extract an inputstream from the file and using it to read the file.

However, this could give me issues if the file is big. What I had in mind was to download a part of the file while the caller was reading it (and caching that part if he came back).

Then, my question would be:

Is it possible, using the OneDrive REST + cpprest downloading a part of a file stored on OneDrive. I have found that uploading files in chunks seems apparently not possible ([Chunked upload (resumable upload) for OneDrive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603176)). Is this true also for the download?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Best regards,

Giuseppe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneDrive supports byte range reads. And so you should be able to request chunks of whatever size you want by adding a Range header.

For example,

```
GET /v5.0/<fileid>/content
Range: bytes=0-1023
```

This will fetch the first KB of the file.

Comment: Thank you for that! As far as you know, is also possible to specify those headers for the upload of a file?

Comment: Range is meant only HTTP retrieval requests such as what you're doing above. Theoretically, the Content-Range header could be used to facilitate a chunked upload mechanism, however as you found from another answer OneDrive does NOT currently support such a semantic.

Comment: There is now some documentation that describes how a chunked upload could work against OneDrive. Have a read of https://gist.github.com/rgregg/37ba8929768a62131e85 and see if it works for you scenario